# Minimax explanation "for dummies"

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm quite new to algorithms and i was trying to understand the minimax, i read a lot of articles,but i still can't get how to implement it into a tic-tac-toe game in python.
Can you try to explain it to me as easy as possible maybe with some pseudo-code or some python code?.

I just need to understand how it works. i read a lot of stuff about that and i understood the basic, but i still can't get how it can return a move.

If you can please don't link me tutorials and samples like (http://en.literateprograms.org/Tic_Tac_Toe_(Python)) , i know that they are good, but i simply need a idiot explanation.

thank you for your time :)

Comment: I'm still in highschool... I learn for passion :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the idea of "minimax" is that there in a two-player game, one player is trying to maximize some form of score and another player is trying to minimize it. For example, in Tic-Tac-Toe the win of X might be scored as +1 and the win of O as -1. X would be the max player, trying to maximize the final score and O would be the min player, trying to minimize the final score.

X is called the max player because when it is X's move, X needs to choose a move that maximizes the outcome after that move. When O players, O needs to choose a move that minimizes the outcome after that move. These rules are applied recursively, so that e.g. if there are only three board positions open to play, the best play of X is the one that forces O to choose a minimum-value move whose value is as high as possible.

In other words, the game-theoretic minimax value V for a board position B is defined as

```
 V(B) = 1   if X has won in this position
 V(B) = -1  if O has won in this position
 V(B) = 0   if neither player has won and no more moves are possible (draw)
```

otherwise

```
 V(B) = max(V(B1), ..., V(Bn)) where board positions B1..Bn are
        the positions available for X, and it is X's move
 V(B) = min(V(B1), ..., V(Bn)) where board positions B1..Bn are
        the positions available for O, and it is O's move
```

The optimal strategy for X is always to move from B to Bi such that V(Bi) is maximum, i.e. corresponds to the gametheoretic value V(B), and for O, analogously, to choose a minimum successor position.

However, this is not usually possible to calculate in games like chess, because in order to calculate the gametheoretic value one needs to enumerate the whole game tree until final positions and that tree is usually extremely large. Therefore, a standard approach is to coin an "evaluation function" that maps board positions to scores that are hopefully correlated with the gametheoretic values. E.g. in chess programs evaluation functions tend to give positive score for material advantage, open columns etc. A minimax algorithm them minimaximizes the evaluation function score instead of the actual (uncomputable) gametheoretic value of a board position.

A significant, standard optimization to minimax is "alpha-beta pruning". It gives the same results as minimax search but faster. Minimax can be also casted in terms of "negamax" where the sign of the score is reversed at every search level. It is just an alternative way to implement minimax but handles players in a uniform fashion. Other game tree search methods include iterative deepening, proof-number search, and more.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain this, I searched for a while before finding this post and it is helpful in learning about minimax

Answer (score 3):

Minimax is a way of exploring the space of potential moves in a two player game with alternating turns.  You are trying to win, and your opponent is trying to prevent you from winning.

A key intuition is that if it's currently your turn, a two-move sequence that guarantees you a win isn't useful, because your opponent will not cooperate with you.  You try to make moves that maximize your chances of winning and your opponent makes moves that minimize your chances of winning.

For that reason, it's not very useful to explore branches from moves that you make that are bad for you, or moves your opponent makes that are good for you.

Comment: Ok... But how can i apply it in a tic tac toe game for example?